# Bulk collect limit with execute immediate

Tags: oracle, bulk, collect, execute-immediate

For operating on millions of records I want to put a limit of 500 but the following code gives error.
Error report:
ORA-06550: line 6, column 49:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "LIMIT" when expecting one of the following:

```
DECLARE
    TYPE EMP_T IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
    EMP_ID EMP_T;
    QRY VARCHAR2(4000):='SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID FROM EMPLOYEES';
begin   
    execute immediate QRY bulk collect into EMP_ID LIMIT 500;
END;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Bulk Collect Into" and "Execute Immediate" in Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21117021/bulk-collect-into-and-execute-immediate-in-oracle)

Comment: `LIMIT 500`. I guess you dont understand why LIMIT is used and whats the best LIMIT you can put for bulk collect. LIMIT simply is not  a number of row counter. If you want a row counter use that in your dynamic query to restrict row. Read this . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38659739/setting-a-value-for-limit-while-using-bulk-collect

Answer (score 0):

That's not the way to use LIMIT clause. I think you can't use LIMIT clause in BULK COLLECT with EXECUTE IMMEDIATE. [BULK COLLECT LIMIT in EXECUTE IMMEDIATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33718417/bulk-collect-limit-in-execute-immediate)

***Example:***

```
DECLARE
    TYPE EMP_T IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
    EMP_ID EMP_T;
    CURSOR c_data IS SELECT empid FROM EMPLOYEE;
begin   
OPEN c_data;
  LOOP
    FETCH c_data
    BULK COLLECT INTO EMP_ID LIMIT 100;
    EXIT WHEN EMP_ID.count = 0;

    -- Process contents of collection here.
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(EMP_ID.count || ' rows');
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE c_data;
END;
/
```

Comment: I can't use cursor as my query is not static. Query is built dynamically and then used in execute immediate.

Comment: If you are using Oracle 12c you can use the row limiting clause, something like FETCH FIRST 500 ROWS